# why multicast can not receive message after running a while? How to deal with it?

Tags: c, sockets

when join multicast, it runs well. But, about 1 hours later, the client can not receive the message sended by the server.Why?

this is running on centos 7.5

```
port_new->bind_addr.sin_family              =   AF_INET;
port_new->bind_addr.sin_port                =   cmcc_htons(port);
port_new->bind_addr.sin_addr.s_addr         =   inet_addr(maddr);

port_new->mreq.imr_interface.s_addr         =   cmcc_htonl(INADDR_ANY);
port_new->mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr         =   inet_addr(maddr);

port_new->sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);    
if (port_new->sock_fd < 0)
{
    goto socket_error;
}

ret = setsockopt(port_new->sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &port_new->mreq, sizeof(port_new->mreq));
if(ret < 0)
{
    printf("setsockopt() IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP error: %s(errno: %d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    goto setsockopt_error;
}


ret = setsockopt(port_new->sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, ttl);
if(ret < 0)
{
    printf("setsockopt() IP_MULTICAST_TTL error: %s(errno: %d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    goto setsockopt_error;
}

ret = setsockopt(port_new->sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &loop, sizeof(loop));
if(ret < 0)
{
    printf("setsockopt() IP_MULTICAST_LOOP error: %s(errno: %d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    goto setsockopt_error;
}

ret = bind(port_new->sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&port_new->bind_addr,  sizeof(port_new->bind_addr));
if(ret < 0)
{
    printf("bind() error: %s(errno: %d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    goto bind_error;
}

return port_new;
```

bind_error:
setsockopt_error:
    close(port_new->sock_fd);
socket_error:
    cmcc_free(port_new);
    return NULL;

Comment: Are you running this code once or in a loop?